# CakePHP projects Session not working

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I've to CakePHP projects like:

```
project1 (main domain: http://www.example1.com)
   /app
   ...
   /project2 (sub folder domain: http://www.example2.com)
```

When hitting url for `project1` it's working fine, but when visiting the `project2`, the `$this->Session->write()` isn't working, ie. Session is not working.

Write now this is session to `project2/app/Config/core.php`:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'project2_cookie_service',
    //'timeout' => 525949
));
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your `app/Config/core.php` change `Session.cookie` to another name. Your root project takes the default name CAKEPHP so change it for the sub-domain project to get another session.

From the following resource, you are able to change session save path of the project2 to prevent interference between it and project1 :

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'ini' => array(
        'session.cookie_path' => '/app/dir'
    )
));
```

Checkout [this official resource](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#session-configuration)

Comment: yes.. used that already but not working, actually its not sub-domain, its sub folder with different domain name. please check my update question and help me please.